# How to use mandrill module with flask security?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, mandrill, flask-security

Can I use mandrill modules for Flask-security mails?

I know flask-security is using Flask-mail module but I want to use mandrill instead.

Comment: Flask-Security talk with Flask-Mail to sending email, You can fork flask-sequrity code

Answer (score 2):

Use [flask-mandrill](https://github.com/volker48/flask-mandrill), and make [flask-security](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security) send its emails using it:

```
from flask.ext.mandrill import Mandrill

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MANDRILL_API_KEY'] = 'your api key'
app.config['MANDRILL_DEFAULT_FROM'] = 'admin@yourdomain.com'

mandrill = Mandrill(app)

@security.send_mail_task
def send_email(msg):
    mandrill.send_email(
        from_email=msg.sender,
        subject=msg.subject,
        to=map(lambda recipient: {'email': recipient}, msg.recipients),
        html=msg.html
    )
```

Comment: map() in Python 3 is a generator function, which is not serializeable in JSON. Wrapping it in a list can resolve: `to=list(map(lambda recipient: {'email': recipient}, msg.recipients)), html=msg.html`

Comment: How to add cc   email id